# Is congratulating non-Muslims on their festivals permissible?

Tags: non-muslim, shirk, celebration

Is it allowed for us as Muslims to congratulate Christians in their eids? (I.e. Merry Christmas, etc.)

> {This day, I have perfected your religion for you, completed My favor upon you, and have chosen for you Islam as your religion} [Quran 5:3](https://quran.com/5/3)

Does wishing constitute to accepting their religion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's two different opinion on congratulating non Muslims on their holidays. some says it's `Haram` and the other said it's `Halal` but with conditions.

According to `Yousuf Al Qaradawi's` `fatwa`, you can congratulating them if you living together in peace specially if there was a relation between you and the one you want to congrats. like work or friendship relation. and it's one of the good manners that Islam does not prevent it.
Allah says: "

> إِنَّ اللَّهَ يُحِبُّ الْمُقْسِطِينَ
>   " `الممتحنة`.

also `The European council for fatwa and research` said it's `Halal` as well.

Source:

- [Qaradawi's fatwa](http://www.qaradawi.net/2010-02-23-09-38-15/4/4806-2009-12-29-18-23-28.html)
- [OnIslam.net](http://www.onislam.net/arabic/ask-the-scholar/8308/8241/65916-2007-12-31%2009-20-33.html)
- [The European council for fatwa and reasearch](http://e-cfr.org/new/?fatwa=%D9%85%D8%A7-%D8%AD%D9%83%D9%85-%D8%AA%D9%87%D9%86%D8%A6%D8%A9-%D8%BA%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%A3%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87%D9%85%D8%9F-3)